# C# Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'parameters'

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, object, compiler-errors

Trying rephrase and solve:

```
namespace Timing_Designer
{
    public partial class TD : Form
    {
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> dictSignals = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
```

...

```
    switch (partType)
    {
        
        case "Clocks":
            Clocks tClass = new Clocks();
            dictSignals.Add(signalName, tClass);
            object currClass = dictSignals[signalName];
            txtExceptions.Text = currClass.ToString();
            List<string> myParams = currClass.parameters; <--- Error line
            break;
        default:
            // Need to make this a prompt!
            txtExceptions.Text = "No Signal Name: \"" + signalName + " \"Found\r\n\r\n";
            return;
    }
```

Getting this error:
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'parameters' and no accessible extension method 'parameters' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I comment out the List line I get no errors, which I am assuming that indicates I do have a dictionary entry with the key-name signalName.

txtExceptions.Text reads: Timing_Designer.Clocks which seems to indicate that I did in fact load a copy of the Clocks class as an instantiated object into the dictionary.

What I don't understand and can't get around is the CS1061 Compiler Error.

This has got to be staring me in the face!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the compiler is telling you is true. `object` indeed does not have a member called `parameters`. Should you have declared `currClass` to be of type `dynamic` instead?

Comment: Thanks! I was not familiar with the dynamic type...